# Ruby trainwrecks

Tags: ruby

The following code:

```
class Avalon 
  def h
    puts "petrezselyem"
  end
end
Avalon.new.h
```

prints out `"petrezselyem"`. However, if I type:

```
puts Avalon.new.h.size
```

It gives

```
undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError).
```

Could you please explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the signature of [Kernel#puts](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-puts):

```
puts(obj, ...) → nil
```

This means `puts` will always return `nil` and since it's the last statement in the `h` method, this will also be the return value of that method.

Comment: I see, just like a println wouldn't return what its printing. Beginners mistake... :)

Answer (score 6):

The method `h` does not return `"petrezselyem"`, it prints out `"petrezselyem"`.  So `Avalon.new.h == nil`.

Java would give you a compile error, but a dynamic language like Ruby does not know the type returned.

Comment: The solution would be to change `puts "petrezselyem"` to `"petrezselyem"` or `return "petrezselyem"`. Then you *can* do `puts Avalon.new.h.size`.

Comment: @Mischa: Or `"petrezselyem".tap { |s| puts s }` ;-) And no, I'm not serious, but it works.

Comment: Every method returns something; in this case the result of `puts`, which is always `nil`.